# How to use ng-repeat on this format of data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use ng-repeat on this format of data?

controller:

```
$scope.makes = [
        {
       "makes": [
          {
             "id": 200347864,
             "name": "AM General",
             "niceName": "am-general"
          },
{
             "id": 200347800,
             "name": "Toyota",
             "niceName": "toyota"
          }
            ]
        }

      ];
```

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MakeListCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="make in makes">


      <p >name: {{make.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: ng-repeat="make in makes[0].makes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body ng-controller="MakeListCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="maker in makes"> 
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="make in maker.makes"> 
         <p >name: {{make.name}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: But I have multiple makes so [0] will be too specific. Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks okay. But better use $http calls in a service or factory. And inject the service/factory in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can just make array object simple like. no need to change in html just change in js

### html

```
<body ng-controller="MakeListCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="make in makes">    
      <p >name: {{make.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

### controller

```
$scope.makes = [
    {
        "id": 200347864,
        "name": "AM General",
        "niceName": "am-general"
    },
    {
        "id": 200347864,
        "name": "AM General",
        "niceName": "am-general"
    },
    {
        "id": 200347864,
        "name": "AM General",
        "niceName": "am-general"
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body ng-controller="MakeListCtrl">
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="make in makes[0].makes">


       <p >name: {{make.name}}</p>
     </li>
   </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="MakeListCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="maker in makes">
        <li ng-repeat="make in maker.makes"> 
         <p >name: {{make.name}}</p>
        </li>
  </ul>
</body>

 Above will be a better way please try this.
```